# How to properly join two tables to use alternative ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, join

Two tables...

1. `people (personid, name, mainordering)`
2. `entries (userid, personid, altordering)`

"personid" is the common field.  My app displays a draggable list users can move around. When done, they click to "lock" in their order.

**Table : people**

```
+----------+---------+--------------+
| personid | name    | mainordering |
+----------+---------+--------------+
| 1        | Bob     |   2          |
| 2        | Charlie |   4          |
| 3        | Jim     |   1          |
| 4        | Doug    |   3          |
+----------+---------+--------------+
```

So using mainordering, it would display:

```
Jim
Bob
Doug
Charlie
```

entries table might have (for user 16):

```
+--------+----------+-------------+
| userid | personid | altordering |
+--------+----------+-------------+
| 16     |   1      |   3         |
| 16     |   2      |   1         |
| 16     |   3      |   2         |
| 16     |   4      |   4         |
+--------+----------+-------------+
```

So if user 16 has already submitted his entry BUT NOT LOCKED IT IN, I want to display his list using `altordering`. i.e.

```
Charlie
Jim
Bob
Doug
```

I'm struggling with the proper join to use.  Here is what I tried and isn't working (it's simply ordering by `mainordering` still)...

```
$sql = "SELECT * from entries
    WHERE userid=".$_SESSION['userid']."
    LEFT JOIN people ON entries.personid = people.personid
    ORDER BY altordering";
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't get an error when using `WHERE` before `JOIN`?

It should work like this:

```
SELECT people.*
FROM people
JOIN entries ON entries.personid = people.personid
WHERE entries.userid={$_SESSION['userid']}
ORDER BY entries.altordering
```

I assume `entries.personid` will always have a matching person in `people`, so you should use an `INNER JOIN`. You would use `FROM entries LEFT JOIN people` if you wanted to retrieve `altordering` even for non-existing `people`.

Comment: Thank you. After you pointed it out, I did find an issue and when corrected, it did kick me an error as you said it should (with WHERE before JOIN).  Anyway, your code worked perfectly, thanks so much for your help/knowledge.